# Laravel Lumen Error: I got error while implementing lumen in fullstack laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I added Laravel lumen in full stack Laravel framework but I got API routing issue like below. Please help me to solve below problem.

I added bootstrap/api.php for use lumen in laravel framework. I configure lumen like below in Laravel framework.

**bootstarp/api.php**

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
```

**App\Providers\AppServiceProvider**

```
$this->app->singleton('Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory', function ($app) {
        return new ResponseFactory(
            $app['Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory'],
            $app['Illuminate\Routing\Redirector']);
});
```

After adding above code in `AppServiceProvider`, I get this error:

> Target [Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollectionInterface] is not instantiable while building [Illuminate\Routing\Redirector, Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you keep saying things like "lumen in laravel", they are 2 different frameworks

Comment: Yes, but I tried to implement Lumen in Laravel framework so I modified public/index.php when URL like /api/* fired I loaded bootstarp/api.php. In api.php for bootstrap lumen.

Comment: they are separate frameworks, you can't implement Lumen in Laravel

Comment: Yes, I know that but I tried to combine both for use 2 different purpose like web for full stack Laravel and Lumen power for APIs work. I successfully implemented in 2 different configuration in bootstrap folder. When fire API then I got error "Target [Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollectionInterface] is not instantiable while building [Illuminate\Routing\Redirector, Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator]"

Comment: make them 2 different sites